# Split HTML table to multi div(s)

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with an `HTML` table. I want my table to appear as newspaper writing style.

[Please Check Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tq7H9.png)

[Desired Home Page sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f8MF.png)

I have no idea how to jump to another div column if 50 records were filled in current div column. I am new to HTML. Thank you for reading my problem.

Current HTML :

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#quotescointainer{
width: 100%;
font-size: 4px;
overflow: hidden; /* contain floated elements */
background: #fff
}
#quotesleft {
float: left; 
width: 10%;
background-color: #fff;
}
#quotescenter { 
float: left;
background-color: #fff;
width: 10%;
}
#quotescenter2 { 
float: left;
background-color: #fff;
width: 10%;
}
#quotescenter3 { 
float: left;
background-color: #fff;
width: 10%;
}
#quotescenter4 { 
float: left;
background-color: #fff;
width: 10%;
}
#quotescenter5 { 
float: left;
background-color: #fff;
width: 10%;
}
#quotescenter6 { 
float: left;
background-color: #fff;
width: 10%;
}
#quotescenter7 { 
float: left;
background-color: #fff;
width: 10%;
}
#quotescenter8 { 
float: left;
background-color: #fff;
width: 10%;
}
#quotesright{
float: left;
width: 10%;
background-color: #fff;
}       
</style>
<style>
table {
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
font-size:0.7vw;
}

td, th {
border: 1px solid #000000;
text-align: left;
padding: 1px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>

    </head>
<body>
<div id="quotescointainer">
<div id="quotesleft">
    <?php echo file_get_contents("http://example.com/table?id=5452") ;?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I could not able to understand what do you want. "I want my table to be appeared as newspaper writing style"

Comment: I've 10 div columns in main page, want to fill each to 50 rows of data . Please check image to clear more. Thank you.

Comment: There was 500 serial data to be appeared in main page. so I need to fill 50 rows in 10 div(s). But I've no idea on how to jump to another div if there was 50 rows after.

Comment: Technically its not possible, you may need to have multiple tables dynamically and put them parallel.

Comment: Probably not exactly what you are looking for but try to look into http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp. Generally speaking I think you need to review your approach once again.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I think I am on the wrong way and I should try to fix it in mysql/php , something , limit rows or show rows between variables and call them parallel like that.  Thank you so much.

Comment: You show alot of HTML, but *none* of the relevant HTML.

Comment: Doesn't multicolumn layout (`column-width` etc., see https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/) with fixed container height automatically do this?

Answer (score 0):

An easier fix for you problem would be to use the DataTables plugin. Also, it's much clearer.

You can just add something like this, with your preferences of course:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```

[See link](https://datatables.net/)